# I can't convert tkinter to exe

Tags: python, tensorflow, tkinter, exe, tensor

I can't convert to exe
I am getting `Failed to execute script temp` fault when I build to execute:

```python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

root = Tk()
root.geometry("550x300+300+150")
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

def openfn():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='open')
    return filename
def open_img():
    img_name = openfn()
    img = Image.open(img_name)
    img = img.resize((250, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    panel = Label(root, image=img)
    panel.image = img
    panel.grid(columnspan=2)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model')

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    img = cv2.imread(img_name)
    img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
    img = np.reshape(img,[1,224,224,3])

    classes = model.predict(img)

    LABELS = ["Actinic keratoses and intraepithelial carcinoma / Bowen's disease",
              "basal cell carcinoma",
              "benign keratosis-like lesions",
              "dermatofibroma",
              "melanoma",
              "melanocytic nevi",
              "vascular lesions"]
    for i in range(0,7):
        if (classes[0][i] == 1):
            j = i
    w = Label(root, text=LABELS[j])
    w.grid(row=2,column=3)

btn = Button(root, text='BUL', command=open_img).grid(row=0,column=0)
btn2 = Button(root, text='ÇIKIŞ', command=root.destroy).grid(row=1,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT1:**
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.7.3
Building directory: C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --noconsole --add-data "C:/Users/safa/.spyder-py3/my_model;."  "C:/Users/safa/.spyder-py3/deneme/myfirstprog.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --noconsole --add-data C:/Users/safa/.spyder-py3/my_model;. C:/Users/safa/.spyder-py3/deneme/myfirstprog.py --distpath C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\application --workpath C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\build --specpath C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0

33176 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0.dev0
33182 INFO: Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
33186 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
33189 INFO: wrote C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\myfirstprog.spec
33194 INFO: UPX is not available.
33199 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\Users\safa\.spyder-py3\deneme',
 'C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0']
33231 INFO: checking Analysis
33236 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
33239 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
33246 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
33261 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
38064 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
38177 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
38197 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\safa\anaconda3\python.exe
38471 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\safa.spyder-py3\deneme\myfirstprog.py
39660 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
39665 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib'
45100 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-site.py'.
45104 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\fake-modules'
47556 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
56923 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-six.moves.py'.
76790 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
175589 INFO: Processing module hooks...
175594 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-babel.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
175791 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-bcrypt.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
175796 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
175805 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-Crypto.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
175872 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
176115 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cv2.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
176120 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
176126 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-docutils.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
178479 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
178571 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
178807 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
235809 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement greenlet from package gevent.
235816 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['cffi']
237548 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-h5py.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
237554 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
237561 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-IPython.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
238195 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
238210 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module IPython.lib.clipboard
238217 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
238232 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
238239 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
238254 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
238258 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
238267 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtSvg from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
238271 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
238281 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtWidgets from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
238288 INFO: Excluding import 'gtk'
238306 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
238319 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
238325 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
238345 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
238350 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
238355 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.backend_bases from module IPython.core.pylabtools
238363 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
238370 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
238376 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jedi.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
239185 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
239210 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jsonschema.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
239237 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
239300 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
239308 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
239977 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
240360 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
240822 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends__init__.py)
241592 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
242158 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
242492 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
243009 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
243341 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
243842 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
244346 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
244819 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
245284 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
245626 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
245948 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
246289 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
246617 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed
247057 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
247492 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
247832 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
248165 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
248596 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
249089 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
249377 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nacl.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
249405 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbconvert.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
249558 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-nbformat.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
249624 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-notebook.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
252349 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.core.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
252468 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
252476 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-openpyxl.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
252616 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
253529 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
253976 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
253991 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
254005 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
254012 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
254033 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
254049 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
254058 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
254067 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
254084 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
254092 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
254111 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
254125 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
254132 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
254956 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-win32com.py'.
255296 INFO: Excluding import '**main**'
255311 INFO:   Removing import of **main** from module pkg_resources
255320 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
255332 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pygments.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
257192 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
265246 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
265254 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
265361 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
265546 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
265877 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
266162 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytest.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
267193 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
267729 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
267927 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
268461 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
268470 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
268485 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
268499 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
268509 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
268523 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
269446 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sphinx.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
274616 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
274850 INFO:   Found 4 sqlalchemy hidden imports
274860 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
274873 WARNING: Hidden import "psycopg2" not found!
276978 WARNING: Hidden import "sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func" not found!
277010 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'sqlalchemy.testing'
277019 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277111 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277121 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tables.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277136 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tensorflow.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277150 WARNING: Hidden import "tensorflow_core" not found!
277164 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277301 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277311 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277325 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
277342 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zmq.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
278437 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
278594 INFO: checking Tree
278604 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
278619 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
278685 INFO: checking Tree
278696 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
278709 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
279032 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
279224 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
279278 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
279291 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
279305 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
279322 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_traitlets.py'
279338 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
279353 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
279369 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
279385 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_certifi.py'
279403 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
279519 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
279759 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
279779 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
280465 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
280479 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
280494 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
280562 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
281012 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
282563 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal_pywrap_profiler.pyd
282591 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal_pywrap_traceme.pyd
284022 INFO: Looking for eggs
284035 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\safa\anaconda3\python37.dll
284053 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
284123 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\build\myfirstprog\warn-myfirstprog.txt
285277 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\build\myfirstprog\xref-myfirstprog.html
285638 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
285659 INFO: checking PYZ
285672 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
285688 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\build\myfirstprog\PYZ-00.pyz
294036 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\build\myfirstprog\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
294212 INFO: checking PKG
294224 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
294242 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
294318 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
294332 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\safa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
294349 INFO: checking EXE
294367 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
294384 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
294409 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\safa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp573jy5x0\build\myfirstprog\myfirstprog.exe
294525 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
294549 INFO: checking COLLECT
294563 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
294581 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
343497 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\Users\safa.spyder-py3\deneme\output
Complete.

i am getting this from auto-py-to-exe and when i am starting program it says failed to execute

Comment: I ran your code and it doesn't run right, something is off. I'm getting `FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1)` warning, are you getting the same error?

Comment: What are you using to convert to an exe?

Comment: auto py to exe i am using now

Comment: 'FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) ' i didint get error like this maybe i use file like model on my local, maybe that cause the problem